# Getting a ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC error when trying to publish a website from VS 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webdeploy

I've been trying to publish a new ASP.NET MVC Core app I wrote, using .NET 6, to a Windows 2019 Server. I followed the instructions on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio. I believe I've done everything on required on this page to deploy a framework-dependent application to the server. .NET 6 has already been installed. In fact, the .NET Core Hosting bundle has been applied to the server.

I've created the website in IIS on the server.

I've made sure I can ping the target server from my development machine.

When I got the ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC I looked up what that error was, which led me to here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC

The Web Management Service wasn't installed, so I had that installed. It is running and set to automatically start.

I've had my IT group double check that port 8172 on the target server is opened so that deploying from VS 2022 using Web Deploy will work. That's fine - it's open and ready to receive deployments.

Here's part of the error:

> Build started...
> 1>------ Build started: Project: Common, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
> 1>Common -> D:\Repos\PW\PharmacyWarehouseV2\Common\bin\Release\net6.0\Common.dll
> 2>------ Build started: Project: PharmacyWarehouseV2, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
> 2>D:\Repos\PW\PharmacyWarehouseV2\PharmacyWarehouseV2\Models\PharmacyDBContext.cs(82,10,82,379): warning CS1030: #warning: 'To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.'](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.%27)
> 2>D:\Repos\PW\PharmacyWarehouseV2\PharmacyWarehouseV2\Controllers\SiteToSiteController.cs(44,30,44,43): warning CS8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
> 2>PharmacyWarehouseV2 -> D:\Repos\PW\PharmacyWarehouseV2\PharmacyWarehouseV2\bin\Release\net6.0\PharmacyWarehouseV2.dll
> 2>Done building project "PharmacyWarehouseV2.csproj".
> 3>------ Publish started: Project: PharmacyWarehouseV2, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
> PharmacyWarehouseV2 -> D:\Repos\PW\PharmacyWarehouseV2\PharmacyWarehouseV2\bin\Release\net6.0\PharmacyWarehouseV2.dll
> PharmacyWarehouseV2 -> D:\Repos\PW\PharmacyWarehouseV2\PharmacyWarehouseV2\obj\Release\net6.0\PubTmp\Out
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("OURSERVER") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)

I've done everything I could do, but I still get that ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC whenever I try to deploy to the target server. What am I missing? There must be something more, other than what I've found in the instructions.

Comment: Try the following methods and try to fix your issue:
A. First double check in Web Deploy settings that the website's name is exactly the same with the one in IIS.
B. If you install Web Deploy BEFORE Web Management Tools are installed, you'll have to re-install Web Deploy.

Comment: @XiaotianYang I'll check the Web Deploy settings tomorrow when I'm working. I'm sure that we installed Web Deploy before the Web Management Tools. I asked for Web Deploy to be installed weeks ago, before discovering I needed the Web Management Tools added only last week.

Comment: @RodYou misunderstand my comment, what I mean is that you can try to re-install the Web Deploy because you installed Web Deploy **before** the Web Management Tools. WMT should be installed first.

Comment: @XiaotianYang oh, you're right, I did misunderstand you. BTW, I've checked the Web Deploy within VS. It is identical to what's in IIS on the server. Another thing, in VS's Publish window, at the bottom is a link to the website. I clicked on it. I cannot go to it. From IIS on the server, I tried going to the website. It complained about not having SSL (which is wrong, I assigned a cert to it) and when I push through to it, I get an HTTP 403.14 error.

Comment: @XiaotianYang I have performed a repair of Web Deploy on the server. I have double checked that the website is named the same, both in my VS 2022 Publish and in IIS on the server. I'm still getting that ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC. I can ping the server but cannot ping the website. It is empty, but I would think something would respond. Perhaps I'm wrong about that.

Comment: @Rodd I see, may be the agent pool selected did not have rights for deployment(IP are not whitelisted for production App service). You can follow [this guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4).

Comment: @XiaotianYang thank you for your response. However, I'm trying to deploy from VS 2022 to an internal server on our network. In this case, Azure DevOps Services isn't involved.